# What are some good Apache settings to use with wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, apache

My server has 756m of RAM.  Every few days I get

[error] server reached MaxClients setting, consider raising the MaxClients setting

Comment: The message you get is a message from your server. Please consult your servers manual first to understand what it means. Additionally please consider using a server support forum first, like [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: This is quite clearly from the title asking what sort of Apache tuning should be done specifically for Wordpress.  That is specific enough to belong on wordpress.stackexchange.com IMHO.  Send it back where people with more experience relating to Wordpress may be hanging out.

Answer (score 1):

Have a read through this site: [Optimize Apache for WordPress](http://thethemefoundry.com/blog/optimize-apache-wordpress/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try lowering the file size in the admin panel for PHP and if that does not work try it in the wp-config.php file.

Benny Age 12